# Percentage Change in dc.js/crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I just started with dc.js and was looking at the NASDAQ example on the main site: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

I created [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickd729/vczqodt4/43/) with some sample dummy data and just the two relevant charts for this question.

Similar to the NASDAQ example, I want to have a bubble chart with the Y-Axis being the % Change in value over a timespan controlled by a brush in a different chart. The code for the NASDAQ example does the following:

```
    var yearlyPerformanceGroup = yearlyDimension.group().reduce(
    /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.absGain += v.close - v.open;
        p.fluctuation += Math.abs(v.close - v.open);
        p.sumIndex += (v.open + v.close) / 2;
        p.avgIndex = p.sumIndex / p.count;
        p.percentageGain = p.avgIndex ? (p.absGain / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        p.fluctuationPercentage = p.avgIndex ? (p.fluctuation / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        return p;
    },
    /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.absGain -= v.close - v.open;
        p.fluctuation -= Math.abs(v.close - v.open);
        p.sumIndex -= (v.open + v.close) / 2;
        p.avgIndex = p.count ? p.sumIndex / p.count : 0;
        p.percentageGain = p.avgIndex ? (p.absGain / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        p.fluctuationPercentage = p.avgIndex ? (p.fluctuation / p.avgIndex) * 100 : 0;
        return p;
    },
    /* initialize p */
    function () {
        return {
            count: 0,
            absGain: 0,
            fluctuation: 0,
            fluctuationPercentage: 0,
            sumIndex: 0,
            avgIndex: 0,
            percentageGain: 0
        };
    }
);
```

which I currently interpret as summing(close-open) across all data and dividing by the average of the average daily index. But this is not a percent change formula I am familiar with. (e.g. (new-old)/old x 100)

While it seems to work for the NASDAQ example, my data would be more like the following:

```
country_id,received_week,product_type,my_quantity,my_revenue,country_other_quantity
3,2017-04-02,1,1,361,93881
1,2017-04-02,4,45,140,93881
2,2017-04-02,4,2,30,93881
3,2017-04-02,3,1,462,93881
2,2017-04-02,3,48,497,93881
```

etc.. over many months and product_types.

Let's say I was interested in computing the percent change for a **particular Country**. How do I get the start and end quantities for a given country so I can compute change as end-start/start * 100?

I was thinking of something such as the following (assuming I set up the proper dimensions and everything)

```
var country_dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d['country_id']; })
var received_day_dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d['received_day']; })
var date_min = received_day_dim.bottom(1)[0]['received_day']
var date_max = received_day_dim.top(1)[0]['received_day']
```

Then in my custom reduce function currently in the vein of the example (wrong):

```
var statsByCountry = country_dim.group().reduce(
          function (p, v) {
              ++p.count;
              p.units += +v["my_units"];
              p.example_rate = +v['my_units']/(v['quantity_unpacked']*90) //place holder for total units per day per country
              p.sumRate +=  p.opp_buy_rate;
              p.avgRate = p.opp_buy_rate/p.count;
              p.percentageGain = p.avgRate ? (p.opp_buy_rate / p.avgRate) * 100 : 0;
              p.dollars += +v["quantity_unpacked"]/2;
              // p.max_date = v['received_week'].max();
              // p.min_date
              //dateDimension.top(Infinity)[dateDimension.top(Infinity).length - 1]['distance'] - dateDimension.top(Infinity)[0]['distance']


              return p;
          },
          function (p, v) {
              --p.count;
              if (v.region_id > 2) {
                p.test -= 100;
              }
              p.units -= +v["quantity_unpacked"];
              p.opp_buy_rate = +v['quantity_unpacked']/(v['quantity_unpacked']*90) //place holder for total units per day per country
              p.sumRate -=  p.opp_buy_rate;
              p.avgRate = p.count ? p.opp_buy_rate/p.count : 0;
              p.percentageGain = p.avgRate ? (p.opp_buy_rate / p.avgRate) * 100 : 0;
              p.dollars -= +v["quantity_unpacked"]/2;
              // p.max_date = v['received_week'].max();
              return p;
          },
          function () {
              return {quantity_unpacked: 0,
                      count: 0,
                      units: 0,
                      opp_buy_rate: 0,
                      sumRate: 0,
                      avgRate: 0,
                      percentageGain: 0,
                      dollars: 0,
                      test: 0
              };//, dollars: 0}
          }
  );
```

and my chart:

```
country_bubble
    .width(990)
    .height(250)
    .margins({top:10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left:80})
    .dimension(country_dim)
    .group(statsByCountry)
    .keyAccessor(function (p) {
      return p.value.units;
    })
    .valueAccessor(function (p) { //y alue
      return p.value.percentageGain;
    })
    .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) { //radius
        return p.value.dollars/10000000;
    })
    .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.05)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)        
    .elasticRadius(true)
    .x(d3.scale.linear())
    .y(d3.scale.linear())
    // .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1.2*bubble_xmax]))
    // .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10000000]))
    .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]))
    .yAxisPadding('25%')
    .xAxisPadding('15%')
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)

    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)        

    .on('renderlet', function(chart, filter){
    chart.svg().select(".chart-body").attr("clip-path",null);
 });
```

Originally thought of having something similar to the following in statsbycountry:

```
          if (v.received_day == date_min) {
            p.start_value += v.my_quantity;
          }
          if (v.received_day == date_max) {
            p.end_value += v.my_quantity;
          }
```

This seems a bit clumsy? But if I do this, I don't think this will continually update as other filters change (say time or product)? Ethan suggested I use fake groups, but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Crossfilter isn't going to be much good at this calculation, so it's not really worth trying to wedge it into the Crossfilter paradigm. Do your filtering, then pull out the data in the current filter with `dimension.top(Infinity)` and then calculate your change over a timespan using that data. If you need to display this in a dc.js chart, then do that using a fake group (https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups)

Comment: @Ethan, so are you suggesting I don't use your suggestion of dimension.top(infinity)? What are the alternatives then to do the calculation such that it will update when I change the time range? Sorry, I'm a bit confused and new.

Comment: I'm saying use a dimension but not a group. Use a fake group instead. Sorry, I'm not online much these few weeks so hopefully someone else can help out

Comment: Thanks Ethan for your help, unfortunately through no lack of you trying, I still don't understand how my custom reduce function, my original country_dim dimension, statsByCountry and my fake group come together and what I put where.

Comment: @Ethan, maybe you can give some quick guidance again. Having thought about it a little more I guess my main problem is how do I group by country but order by date so that top(Infinity)[0] and top(Infinity)[array.length - 1] gives me the results I want? I would first need to get the units for each country at the earliest date and latest date. e.g. start_date, 1, 100| end_date, 1, 200| start_date, 2, 50| start_date,2,50 to be able to start the calculation.

Comment: You wouldn't use a custom reduce function for this. Just `dimension.top(Infinity)` and then wrap that in a fake group. Give it a shot and if you can't get it to work, put together a JSFiddle with a simplified example of your problem under the dc.js and Crossfilter tags and I'm sure someone will be happy to take a look!

Comment: Do I pass both groups (country and received_day) since I need to calculate this for each country?

Comment: You wouldn't pass any groups, at least at first. `dimension.top(Infinity)` returns the raw data, which I think you would then want to process to calculate your change by country.

Comment: I'm looking at the fiddle you included and it is not running because of a large number of errors. There is a syntax error, the date format is wrong, and the bubble chart isn't set up so it errors out. Here is a version that displays the line chart you originally put in it: https://jsfiddle.net/whxvpnrg/ It looks like this more or less works. Can you work on getting the bubble-chart working with a simple dim/group you can calculate and then we can work on getting the change calculation by country/product_type working?

Comment: Hey Ethan, after some effort I finally got the fiddle to give a functioning sample of my local version - i guess it wasn't as simple as copying code from my local machine onto it, but a good exercise :)

So this fiddle shows my bare working version without anything to really calculate the percent change. It has my custom "statsByCountry" reduce function where I calculate some relevant statistics for my bubble chart where I use statsByCountry as my group. My area chart has the different product groups per week. I appreciate the guidance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the working fiddle, we can demonstrate one way to do this. I don't really think this is the best way to go about it, but it is the Crossfilter way.

First you need to maintain an ordered array of all data in a group as part of the group using your custom reduce function:

```
var statsByCountry = country_dim.group().reduce(
  function(p, v) {
    ++p.count;
    p.units += +v["my_quantity"];
    p.country_rate = p.units / (1.0 * v['country_other_quantity']) //hopefully total sum of my_quantity divided by the fixed country_other_quantity for that week
    p.percent_change = 50 //placeholder for now, ideally this would be the change in units over the timespan brush on the bottom chart
    p.dollars += +v["my_revenue"];

    i = bisect(p.data, v, 0, p.data.length);
    p.data.splice(i, 0, v);
    return p;
  },
  function(p, v) {
    --p.count;
    p.units -= +v["my_quantity"];
    p.country_rate = p.units / (1.0 * v['country_other_quantity']) //hopefully total sum of my_quantity divided by the fixed country_other_quantity for that week
    p.percent_change = 50 //placeholder for now, ideally this would be the change in units over the timespan brush on the bottom chart
    p.dollars -= +v["my_revenue"];

    i = bisect(p.data, v, 0, p.data.length);
    p.data.splice(i, 1)
    return p;
  },
  function() {
    return {
      data: [],
      count: 0,
      units: 0,
      country_rate: 0,
      dollars: 0,
      percent_change: 0
    }; //, dollars: 0}
  }
);
```

Above, I've updated your reduce function to maintain this ordered array (ordered by `received_week`) under the `.data` property. It uses Crossfilter's `bisect` function to maintain order efficiently.

Then in your `valueAccessor` you want to actually calculate your change in value based on this data:

```
  .valueAccessor(function(p) { //y alue
    // Calculate change in units/day from first day to last day.
    var firstDay = p.value.data[p.value.data.length-1].received_week.toString();
    var lastDay = p.value.data[0].received_week.toString();
    var firstDayUnits = d3.sum(p.value.data, function(d) { return d.received_week.toString() === firstDay ? d.my_quantity : 0 })
    var lastDayUnits = d3.sum(p.value.data, function(d) { return d.received_week.toString() === lastDay ? d.my_quantity : 0 })
    return lastDayUnits - firstDayUnits;
  })
```

You do this in the value accessor because it only runs once per filter change, whereas the reduce functions run once per record added or removed, which can be thousands of times per filter.

If you want to calculate % change, you can do this here as well, but the key question for % calculations is always "% of what?" and the answer to that question wasn't clear to me from your question.

It's worth noting that with this approach your group structure is going to get really big as you are storing your entire data set in the groups. If you are having performance problems while filtering, I would still recommend moving away from this approach and towards one based on a fake group.

Working updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vysbxd1h/1/

Comment: Super helpful Ethan! Thanks!
As you predicted, I did notice a drop in performance using this method (still happy it works though as a first step). Suggestions for moving it into a fake group? Also do you have any suggestions on debugging the valueAccessor and all in the console rather than reading it off of the chart? Easier to double check with exact numbers. Thanks again!

Comment: It appears on my fuller dashboard the data array isn't sorting properly. hmm

Comment: Got everything working! Thanks again Ethan! In my real dashboard I had to put v.received_week when passing in arguments to the bisect function.

Quick question though I'm curious if you could shed some light on. If I put in a console.log in the valueAccessor (or step through the execution), it goes through the country groups several times seemingly repeating the calculations again before finally stopping. e.g. console.log(p.key + firstDay) gives something like 1firstDay, 2firstDay, 3firstDay 8 times or less. Does it have to do with the number of week groups I have in total?

Comment: Glad it's working! The `valueAccessor` will run once per group per update of the chart. So it seems that you are seeing it running once per group, which makes sense to me.